# How to skip a row in when using INDEX & MATCH, if the row is empty?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with two columns A and B where in A there are elements that may repeat themselves and does not have blank cells while Column B have some blank cells. What I need to do is fill the empty column in B using column A as reference.
For Example:

```
A          B
Mary.      apple
Juan.      papaya
Andre.     apple
Sophie.    carrots
Becca
Brian.     banana
Becca.     carrots
```

I need to fill the Empty Becca space in column B with the word carrot since there is a Becca with carrot below and the same with other empty cells in column B, in case there is no answer just leave it blank but if there is an already filled with an specific item I need to complete it with that one.
By the way the answer is in a column C where is "Fixed", column A & B is just where the date is.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Some text has dot at the end of word and some haven't? Is it same as your real data?

Comment: No those dots appear when I was using space to separate the columns, didn't know how to create a table here thx for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ***Microsoft Excel 365*** use below formula to obtain same value for empty cells. Then if you need to replace value in **Column B** copy data from formulas and paste as values to Column B.

```
=@IF(B1="",SORT(FILTER($B$1:$B$7,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,$A$1:$A$7)))),B1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate, that helps a lot.. I was using INDEX MATCH with IF but couldn't fill the empty ones only the ones that were already named.

Comment: Then you can use simplified formula `=@IF(B1="",SORT(FILTER($B$1:$B$7,$A$1:$A$7=A1)),B1)`